# How to access FIXTURES data from the Ember.Handlebars.helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, helper, fixtures, handlebars.js

This is how I have created my ember FIXTURE:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;

App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr(),
parent_id: DS.attr()
});

App.Category.FIXTURES = [
{
   id: 1,
   name: 'user1',
   email: 'user1@gmail.com',
   parent_id: 0
},
{
   id: 2,
   name: 'user2',
   email: 'user2@gmail.com',
   parent_id: 1
}
];
```

Here is a part of my ember view where 'parent-title' is a helper:

```
{{#each category in controller}}
<tr>
  <td>{{category.name}}</td>
  <td>{{parent-title category.parent_id}}</td>
  <td>Edit/Delete</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

What I want is that during listing if the parent_id is 0 it should print 'master' else the name of parent category. In my exapmle parent of user2 is id=1 show it should print 'user1'.
Below is the helper I have used:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('parent-title', function(parent_id){
  if (parent_id > 0) {
    var parent = category.findBy('id', parent_id);
    return parent.name;
  } else {
   return 'master';
  }
});
```

I know if I replace the line `App.Category.FIXTURES = [` with `var Category = [` I can get it done but I want ot do it with FIXTURES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you that accessing data like that is a bad idea. If I were you, I would change `parent_id` to be a relationship, not an attribute (since that's really what it is). Then you can access the parent's name in templates with `category.parent.name`. Making it a relationship also gives you a few other luxuries.

But if you want to maintain backward compatibility, try using a computed property.

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    parent_id: DS.attr(),

    parent: function() {
        return DS.PromiseObject.create({
            promise: this.get('store').find('category', this.get('parent_id'))
        });
    }.property('parent_id'),

    parent_name: function() {
        return this.get('parent.name');
    }.property('parent.name')
});
```

---

EDIT: If you want to change that into a relationship (which I think it should be), it's fairly simple. Instead of `DS.attr`, you use `DS.belongsTo`. For instances.

```
App.Categor = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    // I dropped the _id part because it's no longer an ID
    parent: DS.belongsTo('category', { inverse: null })
});
```

This tells Ember-Data to interpret the ID you give in the `parent` field as another `category` object. So `category.get('parent')` will return another `category` object, not a number. But in your case, to make it work, you'll have to convert all of the `0` IDs to `null` IDs. I wasn't sure if that was possible, which is why I recommended the computed property.

EDIT: To display `master` in case of a null parent, use the Handlebars `if` expression.

```
{{#if parent}}
    {{parent.name}}
{{else}}
    master
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Thanks @GJK for reply. I tried the code you gave. It prints 'master' for `parent_id = 0` but for `else` part it does not return anyhting.Basically it gives 'undefined' for `else` part. Shouldn't there be `findBy` somewhere in the code?
You told I should make `parent_id` as a relationship. Can you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: I was afraid that the else part might not work. You'll have to give me a few minutes to set up a fiddle to test it. In the meantime, I'll edit my answer with how to change it to a relationship.

Comment: Thanks @GJK.. The edited code has spell mistake in 1st line `App.Category` you may want to edit it.
I tried edited code but I still can't get the desired output. `category.get('parent')` in view generated an error and `category.parent` does not print anything.
I am not sure whether I should retain the helper part after using the edited code or not.

Comment: when I use `category.parent` in view it prints `<App.Category:ember384:1>` where `:1` is the `ID` of its parent.

Comment: That's the expected behavior. `category.parent` refers to the actual parent object. If you want a property on that object (like the name), use `category.parent.name`.

Comment: apart from this issue I would be very thankful if you can also help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094049/how-to-create-dropdown-in-ember-js-using-local-storage) issue

Comment: I'll take a look at that issue. If the relationships didn't work for you, I updated the computed property, and it should work now. (I would stick with the relationships if that works though.)

Comment: ok I got the parent name by using `category.parent.name`. Now how can I display 'master' in place of null? Is there any way for it?

Comment: You can use Handlebars expressions for that. Again, I updated my answer.

Comment: DONE!! working fine by using handlebars expression. Thanks @GJK